# Equailzers in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

Is there an equalizer add-on that would work with Spotify? 
I installed the Spotify app, but it indicated that it was not continually supported.

Answer (score 0):

There's system wide equalizer provide by this package: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8/xenial/main/base/pulseaudio-equalizer

However, I'm not sure if it works for a specific software,namely Spotify for Linux which seems to not having much attention lately.